# Most efficient array for working with strings

Tags: python, arrays, performance, list, nlp

I have a corpus of ~600 million words. I would like to turn it into a list of strings and then work with it but I am worried that working with a list of 600 million elements will be quite slow. I am wondering whether there are high-performance equivalents for lists (of words) in Python.

UPDATE:

I want to map each word to one of two labels after computing some score for them. The score is basically a fraction, where the numerator is the frequency in which they appear in certain environments (e.g. before some specified words) and the denominator is their overall corpus frequency. This is pretty much the task I have in mind.

Comment: what exactly does "working with" entail? As stated the question is a bit on the broad side.

Comment: Python is probably not the language for working with data sets that big.

Comment: it depends , if you want to count letters or to cluster words , or to auto-translate.. ,perhaps you give more explanation

Comment: If you're counting them, processing them iteratively (so you're not storing all of them as separate strings in memory at once) could work just fine. You need to give us information on what you'd like to do if you want assistance on more specialized data structures.

Comment: They aren't 600 million unique words right? It depends what you want to do but that doesn't sound like so big a dataset that won't reasonably fit in memory with pretty basic representation techniques.

Comment: So your data structure will just contain unique words and you don't need to read all the data in at once. You can pretty much implement it naively with a dict and chunked (line by line, easiest) reading and it will work just fine. There is no point at which you'll have a list of 600 mil words at all, your resident size will be mere megabytes.

Comment: That's actually a great point! I only need to read a "sentence" each time, operate on it and then move to the next, storing the results in some high-performance dict like Counter. Thanks @pvg!

Answer (score 2):

It really boils-down to your use-case and what you want to do with the "600 million words".

If you are bound to Python, check out [Dask.distributed](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [dispy](http://dispy.sourceforge.net/).  As intboolstring stated, however, Python may not be your best choice.

As an alternative, MapReduce with something like [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) is a great way to process large amounts of data.  You didn't really explain your application environment, so it's tough to provide much insight.

Comment: This an in-memory dataset, really so that stuff is likely huge overkill.

Comment: I have added more details to the question as requested.

Comment: Will your dataset grow in the future?  I assume it will, since you will probably be using different corpuses.  At what rate?  Does your program have any requirements for the rate of processing the words?  Is this an operation you'll only run once?  The operation is clear now, but the environment is a bit fuzzy.

Answer (score 0):

@shadowranger is right,you should tell us more details about what you'd like to do.These are my advice.

- At first, check out your code and find the bottleneck of the problem instead of just guessing.If what you want to do isn't about I/O bound,maybe multiprocessing is a good choice.
- Data structure a very important factor.If you want to work with large object,the best idea is choosing the most suitable data structure.Maybe you can try [deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) which is list-like container with fast appends and pops on either end instead of `list`.

> Deques are a generalization of stacks and queues (the name is
>   pronounced “deck” and is short for “double-ended queue”). Deques
>   support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either
>   side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in
>   either direction.

- Memory management,if the size of data is very large,try to structure this code around `generators` and `iterators` instead of large lists of items,it will help you avoid running out of memory and improve your code.
- [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) maybe helps you with processing large file.

> Memory-mapped file objects behave like both strings and like file
>   objects.

See more details from [High-performance container datatypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

Comment: Details have been added!